# Error while try to create a new user and updating the user in web min

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu-server, webmin, webmin-module-development

I don't know what i did wrong during installation.. I am using ubuntu server 17.04. I can't able to create new user and edit the user. Please help me to understand i am doing wrong

Error:

Can't locate timelocal.pl in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/share/webmin /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base /usr/share/webmin/ . ..) at /usr/share/webmin/useradmin/edit_user.cgi line 6.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting Webmin?